# Not able to authenticate with correct username and password in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am using Django 1.5. My user model is:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    #last_login = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I am not able to authenticate with correct username and password. 
My login function is:

```
def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I have to do now, then?

Comment: I am doing the same. I think the name User won't affect it.

Comment: I think it would be the best way to write custom authentication Backend than to use the beta version of Django to use this feature, rite?

Comment: yeah you can write custom authentication

Comment: I want to authenticate with both username and email. Can you help me on that with the above model. I will mark your answer best. Thanks

Comment: yeah, wait a moment. Sorry for the late reply, I'm eating my dinner

Comment: You must create password field in your User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update your User model, it has no password. Your email field is not charfield I think it's EmailField and your password is not a charfield also. Please search for the correct field. Password must be hash...

**backend.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from app_name.models import User

class AuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Create **"check_password"** function via model. The way this check is, the input password must be hash before comparing it to the password that is being save in the database.

Update **settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'app_name.backend.AuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: That's great but where do I get check_password()?

Comment: create a "check_password" view function for checking the entered password

Comment: It's not a sample, you me to code it. I already provide you the backend authentication so maybe it's your turn to solve the remaining function to complete that. There are many documentation online.

Comment: Did that but getting this error: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: last_login

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the user model in settings.py ?

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

If you have already ran *syncdb* you'll have to drop your database and run it again. See : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model